# Rich Push Notification not hiding the large icon on expanding the notification containing image

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am following the android developers docs to create an expandable notification containing one image.I have written the same code as per the docs but my large icon is not hiding after I expand my notification.
Here's my code:-

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
                            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(data.get("message"))
                            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap)
                                    .bigLargeIcon(null))
                            .setAutoCancel(true).setChannelId(id)
                            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));   

Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        notification.flags |=
        Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; //Do not clear  the notification
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;//Vibration

        notificationManager.notify(mUniqueId, notification);
```

and android developer's code :-

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_post)
    .setContentTitle(imageTitle)
    .setContentText(imageDescription)
    .setLargeIcon(myBitmap)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(myBitmap)
            .bigLargeIcon(null))
    .build();
```

I am not able to understand whether I am missing something or doing it in wrong way. Please help . Thank You in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the vendor-specific API changes. May I know on which device are you trying to achieve this? My bet is it's a Xiaomi device.

Comment: No @Jay , It's Moto G4 plus device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer !! 
Actually it is device specific issue.Some android devices are not hiding the large icon on expanding the notification and some devices are hiding it.